# Building Brave-Browser in Windows doesn't work

Tags: windows, chromium, brave, brave-browser

I am trying to build Brave Browser in Windows 10 64bit 15.8GB RAM and more than 200gb in free space.
I am following this repo: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/wiki

I have installed all the requeriments for the build on Windows, however, when I run npm run init I get the following error:

```
Downloading CIPD client for windows-amd64 from https://chrome-infra-packages.appspot.com/client?platform=windows-amd64&version=git_revision:db7a486094873e3944b8e27ab5b23a3ae3c401e7...
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
        pylint.bat
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
fatal: Could not detach HEAD
Failed to update depot_tools.
```

Anyone knows why that might be happening? I have tried installing python and setting the enviroment variable, rebooting the machine, tried installing VS Code a few times thinking it might be it but the error is always the same. I have also tried the Brave Community and I cannot see anything similar.

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's an upstream problem in Chromium, so a fix should appear in Brave soon. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=996359 for details, including a potential workaround (though I haven't personally tested it).

Comment: thanks, I have applied the work around and the error dissapeared.